# Should the team commit to read authoritative reference bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Up to now [I flushed 1700 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d?tab=bounties&sort=offered) in bounties here on Meta (including this question). Almost every time I choose

> **Authoritative reference needed**: Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

as bounty reason. Rarely I got a response from a DEV/community-manager. I don't even know if such questions ever get noticed by the team. I know they have lots to do. They try [in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180765/172011) and on [bug reports too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports).

I propose to generate an internal list of especially those bounty questions so the team could access it and give a quick response about bug reports or feature-request.

For me it would even be enough if such questions only get tagged like [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) or [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) or whatever. Of course an answer would be even better.

Comment: I have +1'd for the idea in general, but would -1 for the actual implementation. Demanding a response because some *one* slapped a bounty on a question, isn't as applicable to the wider meta-audience as something similar to what [Jeff proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187610/163863)... i.e. demand a response for any [meta-tag:feature-request] over X-votes, and any unsolved-bug report over Y votes.

Comment: I like the implementation. Bounty like that clearly designates, well, just as per bounty type: **Authoritative reference needed** - clearly denoting an expectation for particular kind of reply. Not all bounties / posts are like that, as an example, none of my 130+ bounties were like that (if memory serves:). Alternative implementation would be to remove mentioned bounty reason to avoid setting wrong expectations

Comment: Having a bounty type that would commit the dev/community team's to respond would only cause that bounty type to become overused and it would lose it's usefulness when overused. Now having a bounty type that just brings it to the dev/community team's attention could be helpful though.

Answer (score 6):

Bounties on MSO are rather meaningless, I use them to get a bit more attention for some feature requests, but I don't see why bounties should be the measure to distinguish feature requests worthy of a response. Meta rep is very easy to acquire, I could probably keep up having the maximum number of simultaneous bounties at the minimum bounty value without even losing reputation over time.

I do think that SE could be better at responding to feature requests that receive a lot of support from the community, but I think that votes are a better indicator than bounties.

Comment: Well, votes are better indication what's worth solving / implementing, but bounties are better indication how desperate people are to get a *response* - even if that's a negative or deferring one.

Comment: @Mołot That only works if rep is reasonably scarce and considered somewhat meaningful. Meta rep is considered pretty much useless by many users, if bounties would commit SE to answer I guarantee that the number of bounties would explode. The true measure of how desparate you want something done is how much effort you put into the meta post and into designing the feature.

Comment: In that case, it maybe should be votes indeed, but not the post's score, but total number of votes cast, up and down. After all declining bad requests fast only helps to keep site clean. But now bounty reason suggests it will bring answer from official sources, and it does not. Not a good thing (but may be solved by removing this one from metas).

Comment: If meta rep is so worthless, please feel free to slap some bounties on any of my answers :). I'd love to get past 2000!

Comment: Of all my offered bounties, none of them have been looked at by the team! I feel like bounties are just a way to lose reputation...